# Error message converting pandas dataframe integers to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to convert dates into datetime since they were given to me in YYYYMMDD format on my HW. The date was already indexed for a previous problem so I wrote out:

```
df.reset_index()
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

This is the error message I ended up getting:

```sh
   KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in 
    get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
       3079             try:
    -> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
       3081             except KeyError as err:
    
    pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
    
    pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
    
    pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
    
    pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
    
    KeyError: 'DATE'
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-291-e5a2ae2efa46> in <module>
          1 df.reset_index()
    ----> 2 df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%Y%m%d')
          3 #df.set_index('DATE',inplace=True)
          4 #df.resample('A').apply(lambda x: x[x<0].count())
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
       3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
       3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
    -> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
       3025             if is_integer(indexer):
       3026                 indexer = [indexer]
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
       3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
       3081             except KeyError as err:
    -> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
       3083 
       3084         if tolerance is not None:
    
    KeyError: 'DATE'

Very confused since I pretty much literally used this datetime line for a different problem without any issue. Is there anything I can do to fix this? thanks!
```

Comment: You do not appear to have a `DATE` column. If `DATE` was the index, `df.reset_index()` will not work to update the DataFrame so that `DATE` is a column. [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) is not an in place by default. Did you perhaps mean `df = df.reset_index()`?

Comment: seems i'm an idiot i just needed to add (inplace=True) after the to_datetime... thank you for pointing out that the DATE column was missing though! now to fix the other lines lol

Comment: You're not an idiot. It's very easy to miss the little things. I'm glad you're a bit closer to a solution.